# Raspberry Pi won't recognise USB devices

Tags: usb

I'm having a problem when my Pi starts up that it won't recognise any devices plugged into the USB or ethernet ports. I have tried various power supplies, SD cards and USB combinations, and none of them work. This Pi was wotking perfectly only hours ago but suddenly started with this problem.

When I connect a screen I can see that the startup sequence is far shorter than it should be, and many sections of the startup procedure are missing. I'm also seeing "error opening /dev/input/event* no such file or directory"

Any help with what I can do here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please, do not try to plug USB devices into the ethernet port, this most likely will damage the port and/or device.

Comment: sorry I was unclear, I meant plugging the LAN cable into the ethernet to try SSH

Comment: if you have a spare SD card, please, try to boot a fresh image and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Have done so with no joy. I've also checked the X1 chip with an oscilloscope which is fine, and resoldered it to be sure, still getting the correct reading there

Comment: to update, I have tested the SD card on a friend's Pi and it has no problem, so it is definitely a hardware problem. The X1 crystal is operating fine and the supply voltage is sufficient (5.05V input, 4.91V on the USB ports)